# How to do upstream messaging service using GCM CCS from Android code?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a messaging service using GCM's CCS...I have already implemented GCM in normal way where I used a third-party server and browser key with GCM Sender id to send notification to devices, which works perfectly.

I have tried implementing CCS using the following link

[Tutorial](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial)

Which has two project one is for Android and another one for Java. I am not worried for the server application for time being because I can use PHP features too. However I am not finding a way where Android application is connecting with server application in the code and other examples have same unrealistic ending to the project. If at all I can send the registrationId to my server using HTTP connection, how would I able to send upstream message to GCM-CCS from application?

I want that one device will send a message to CCS Application and that message will be broadcast to all registered devices including the sender.

[image: CCS Broadcast]

The following link for tutorial is a bogus link too, I don't understand what its trying to do.

[Another Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/)

Google must provide a clear representation about CCS-GCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use an XMPP connection to send upstream messages.  See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#upstream for a description of upstream messaging along with sample code.  (This is also where I learned that you need to use XMPP instead of HTTP.  Sorry I don't have more specific answers to offer at the moment, I'm still working out how to do this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this link -

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

a small tutorial- 
 http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

for sending messages from app to backend , you can use json encoding . and POST parms to url or yours server , do something like this  -

```
// Building Parameters

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", post_message));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");



                //Posting user data to script

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(

                        POST_URL, "POST", params);
```

Where JSONObject is yours json parser Sir

a good json parser tutorial -  http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/

As per yours edit , After yours backend recieves the messages  encoded in json , save them in database and then finally use GCM to send messages to all the registered device

Comment: I know how to use HTTP request and I said that too in my question. My question is, is that same with upstream message where the message will be delivered to Google XMPP server so that its using CCS of GCM?

Comment: @Saty Sir,  use json parsing/encoding and make  http request , i iditted it with how  i usually use

Comment: @jimmy...you are not getting my point...I am not worried about the http post or the way I should do it...I am asking about the procedure of GCM-CCS upstream messaging?

Comment: @Saty sir i use json encoding  to upstream messages to my backend GCM ,  as i mentioned - ` params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", your_post_message));
`